# Complex Itemrenderer ( List within a List), Struggling with scrolling behaviour ins second list

Tags: actionscript-3, list, flex4, itemrenderer, vertical-scrolling

I'm struggling for a while with a scrolling problem now.
I'm developing a flex application with some complex views. On of the views is like a word document view. It pulls data from the database and represents requirement specification. You can also edit the data within this "word" view. It should basically work like microsoft word. That view works fine but I have one issue with it: Scrolling!

To realize that view I have created a complex ItemRendererClass that contains another complex ItemRenderClass. Imagine it like that>

-List of chapters (itemrenderer)
- Chapternumber + ChapterTitle
- ChapterText
- Chapterpicture
- List of data (itemrenderer)
- Requirementnumber
- RequirmeentText
- Pictures
- lots and lots of attributes
-...

All in all I'm really happy how the "word" view&editor works but if I'm scrolling down and I'm over the second lists which represents the list of requirements I can't scroll anymore, when the mouse is out of the list item I can scroll again. What I have done is I use virtual layout on both lists for performance reasons and the second lists height is a 100%, so the second scroller never appears. I have tried to disable the second scroller of the second lists with "this.scroller.setStyle('verticalScrollPolicy', 'off')". But nothing happens. What i want is a normal scrolling behaviour, means that it shouldn't matter where in the "wordview" the mouse is I want to scroll like it is one list and not 2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it. Was really easy actually. I just created a skin for the second list where i deleted the scroller component. In addition to that i had to sign the scroller from the second list to the parent List. Works like a charm so far